# Can we update State in ondownloadprogress axios?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-state

I want to update my state **setApiResponse** in *ondownloadprogress* event, on console.log, it's showing data coming through, but when I set my state, it's not updating my state and displaying data.

```
axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:3005/tables",
      onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        console.log(progressEvent.currentTarget.response);
        setApiResponse([progressEvent.currentTarget.response, ...apiResponse]);
      },
    })
```

---

Simply, getting a response by using the response parameter is possible but it's taking time to display data in the table, I want this method to work to display data on the table as soon as data comes through. This will lead to faster rendering and response time.
**Any solution related to this?**

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want your `apiResponse` to be an array?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to be an array so that it can be displayed on the table one by one like streaming data into the table. Any other approach you would recommend?

Comment: What is the data? You would also need to be able to parse it in a streaming manner.

Comment: Exactly, my data is streaming from the MongoDB collection, I am getting streaming response in console.log, but my state is not updating hence not showing data in table.

Comment: _What_ does `/tables` stream? _What_ are you actually getting?

Comment: /tables allow streaming my data in form of JSON, I am getting it perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. If you're getting it perfectly, what is the issue? Also, if that endpoint just returns a single JSON document (instead of eg. NDJSON/JSONLines) it will not be trivial to "stream" it.

Comment: What I want to do is Update state upon getting data, but its not showing me, that's the issue

Comment: Well, your question isn't even showing anything that would use your `ApiResponse`, so it's hard to tell what the issue is.